# Android Studio override/implement methods missed

Tags: android, android-studio, overriding

I want to generate `getParams()` method but android studio override/implement menu doesn't showing any methods. how do i fix it 
[image]

Comment: press ALT + Insert button u will get pop up window there will be override method

Comment: Which classe's is the `getParams()` method that you want to override? Can you post your code instead of images?

Answer (score 1):

Create a Abstract method in your base class like below

```
public abstract void getParams();
```

Answer (score 0):

**quick command search : <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>**

[image: screenShot of SearchBox]

if you have more memory here it is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>